# Setting margin to controls outside Grid with reference to control inside Grid

Tags: wpf, xaml

Working on wpf solution

i have created a Grid with different columns, a control is added in column 2.
Now i have a control outside grid and the Left margin should be same as the control inside the grid.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can of course take the very simple way of changing `Margin` using code.

For pure MVVM approach, you can do that using `AttachedProperty`.

`Binding` with a `Convertor` won't work here as `Thickness` type is not a `DependencyObject`.

If we simply bind the `Margin` of outer `Button` to inner `Button`, Entire `Margin` of outer `Button` will change, which we dont want. So, we need to preserve whole `Margin` except `Left Margin`. `Left Margin` can be changed using `Binding`. But how ? Our outer `Button` needs to have two `Margin` values, one original, and another coming from `inner Button`, so that original one can be changed. For this another margin, we can take help of `Attached Property`, as they allow us to extend a control.

**AttachedProperty**

```
public static BindingExpression GetLefMargin(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (BindingExpression)obj.GetValue(LefMarginProperty);
}

public static void SetLefMargin(DependencyObject obj, BindingExpression value)
{
    obj.SetValue(LefMarginProperty, value);
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LefMargin.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty LefMarginProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LefMargin", typeof(BindingExpression), typeof(Window1), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(MarginCallback)));

private static void MarginCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement elem = d as FrameworkElement;
    BindingExpression exp = e.NewValue as BindingExpression;            

    // Create a new Binding to set ConverterParameter //

    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Converter = exp.ParentBinding.Converter;
    b.ConverterParameter = elem.Margin;
    b.Path = exp.ParentBinding.Path;
    b.ElementName = exp.ParentBinding.ElementName;
    b.Mode = exp.ParentBinding.Mode;

    elem.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.MarginProperty, b);
}
```

**Converter**

```
public class LeftMarginCnv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double gridCtrlLeftMargin = ((Thickness)value).Left;
        Thickness tgtCtrlMargin = (Thickness)parameter;

        return new Thickness(gridCtrlLeftMargin, tgtCtrlMargin.Top, tgtCtrlMargin.Right, tgtCtrlMargin.Bottom);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Red" Margin="29,55,52,125" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="121*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="Btn" Content="Press" Margin="18,22,35,28" Grid.Column="1" Click="Btn_Click"/>            
    </Grid>
    <Button local:Window1.LefMargin="{Binding Margin, ElementName=Btn, Converter={StaticResource LeftMarginCnvKey}}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

Outer `Button` will change its `Left Margin` if you change the Left margin of inner `Button`.

Comment: @ShobhaM Plz check updated answer, and ask doubts one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the common style for both.  Something like this.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="commonstyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0" />
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox x:Name="outside" Width="100" Height="70" Style="{StaticResource commonstyle}"/>
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Width="100" Height="70" x:Name="inside" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource commonstyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

(or)

Make it simple

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBox x:Name="outside" Width="100" Height="70" Margin="{Binding ElementName=inside, Path=Margin}"/>
   <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Width="100" Height="70" x:Name="inside" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Hope that helps.